# Exception in thred django-main-thread:

Tags: python, django

## Creating forms from models

i'm new to django and try to models form but unfortunate get some bizarre error even i twice check my code as well i checked django documentation but not figure out my issue...

i visit this django documentation but not figure out yet!!! quite confusing!

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/

AppFive/forms.py

```
from django import forms
from AppFive.models import User
from django.forms import ModelForm

class NewUserForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__ ' # <-- Mistake over here - This Line. SOLVED!
```

AppFive/models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class User(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=264,unique=True)
```

AppFive/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
# from django.http import HttpResponse
# from AppFive.models import User
# Create your views hereself.
from AppFive.forms import NewUserForm

def index(request):
    return render(request,'AppFive/index.html')

def users(request):
    form = NewUserForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = NewUserForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=True)
            return index(request)
        else:
            print('ERROR : F O R M    I N V A L I D')
    return render(request,'AppFive/users.html',{'form':form})
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Khan\Miniconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Khan\Miniconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Khan\Miniconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Khan\Miniconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Users\Khan\Miniconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 390, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "C:\Users\Khan\Miniconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 377, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Khan\Miniconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\Users\Khan\Miniconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 40, in check_url_namespaces_unique
    all_namespaces = _load_all_namespaces(resolver)
  File "C:\Users\Khan\Miniconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 57, in _load_all_namespaces
    url_patterns = getattr(resolver, 'url_patterns', [])
  File "C:\Users\Khan\Miniconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\Khan\Miniconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 579, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\Khan\Miniconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\Khan\Miniconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 572, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Users\Khan\Miniconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Khan\Desktop\Python Bootcamp\PB2\ProFive\ProFive\urls.py", line 18, in <module>
    from AppFive import views
  File "C:\Users\Khan\Desktop\Python Bootcamp\PB2\ProFive\AppFive\views.py", line 5, in <module>
    from AppFive.forms import NewUserForm
  File "C:\Users\Khan\Desktop\Python Bootcamp\PB2\ProFive\AppFive\forms.py", line 5, in <module>
    class NewUserForm(ModelForm):
  File "C:\Users\Khan\Miniconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 235, in __new__
    raise TypeError(msg)
TypeError: NewUserForm.Meta.fields cannot be a string. Did you mean to type: ('__all__ ',)?
```

python 3.7.4

django (2, 2, 3, 'final', 0)

Comment: Post your code, otherwise it's kind of impossible to help.

Comment: `fields` in `class Meta` must be a list of field name or `'__all__' . It's not any other string.

Comment: now i post code (sorry i forgot to post code stuff)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fields = '__all__ '
```

It has an extra space in the string. Remove it!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by caot, you need to provide the code for correct answer. Anyway, let me make a guess.

When you try to generate a form out of a model, you need to specify the model as well as the fields in it (that you are interested in displaying / capturing).

The fields should be assigned a list consisting (strictly) of field names, each as a string. If you intend to include all fields, '**all**' as a string (yes, string; not a list) can be specified.

I guess, either you made a mistake in specifying **all** or you included the fields as a string (fields = 'pub_date' or fields = 'pub_date, headline')

If my answer does not solve your issue, please show the full code.

Cheers